# Should I apply envelope of parabola or is there an easier way out?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Suppose we are at the top of a $10$ m  tall building and we are free to throw a ball at any angle from the top with a speed of $10\sqrt2ms^{-2}$ .What is its maximum possible horizontal range on the ground as measured from the bottom of the building? Also if possible find the angle of projection with the horizontal.

Should I apply envelope of parabola or am I missing something trivial? So how do I solve it?

Thanks for explaining the method!!

Comment: For a same level maximum reach it works to find the extrema for $x(\theta)$, first manipulating the equations of motion to get the function ($\theta=\pi/4$). It has to work too for your problem (and by intuition, the agle is the same). Anyway, to calculate the envelope is a nice way to do that!!

Comment: try to research: $x_{max}=v_0\cos \alpha\left ( \frac{v_0\sin \alpha}{g}+\sqrt{\left ( \frac{v_0\sin \alpha}{g} \right )^2+\frac{2H_0}{g}} \right )$